# Get current month from column into ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datetime, observablecollection

Into `DataGrid` I'm displaying all "working" days in month (column DateColumn):

```
ColX  |  DateColumn | ColZ
  1   |  2018-09-03 |  A
  10  |  2018-09-04 |  AA
  8   |  2018-09-05 |  A1
  234 |  2018-09-06 |  C20
```

Now I'm trying build method that will be changed the list of dates to Next and Previous Month. My problem is to get current Month from my `ObservableCollection`.

```
private void PrevMonth_Executed(object obj)
{
  //Console.WriteLine(MyConceptItems.ElementAt(0).DateColumn);--2018-09-03
  int month = DateTime.ParseExact(MyConceptItems.ElementAt(0).
              DateColumn, "YYYY-MM-DD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month
}
```

It get me below error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: @mm8 it is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `DateColumn` is a `DateTime` you could just do this:

```
int month = MyConceptItems.ElementAt(0).DateColumn.Month;
```

If it's a `string` you should really change the type to `DateTime`. Or use the following format when you parse the `string` value:

```
int month = DateTime.ParseExact(MyConceptItems.ElementAt(0).DateColumn, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
```

Comment: thank you @mm8, working for string, but I will try to change it to the DateTime